# Phrase-usage: Where has this come from? Or Where did this come from?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, present-perfect, past-simple

Something that is confusing me is:

> Hey dude, Where  **has this come**/ **did this come** from?

I know how to use Present Perfect, but, I don't know if using here sounds natural. Can I use both? But, of course the answers would be different. At least, this is what I think

> Dude, where *has this come* from?
>
> It's come from Dallas. 5 milles from here

/

> Dude, where *did this come* from?
>
> It came from Dallas yesterday. 5 milles from here.

Comment: Regarding your question, this Google Books Ngram Viewer graph shows that for most of the last 200 years, **did** has been beaten **has** handsomely. The exception was for a brief period in the 1930s. Over the last 50 years, **did** has accelerated away from **has** - although both are perfectly idiomatic.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where+has+this+come+from%2Cwhere+did+this+come+from&year_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both are technically grammatically correct, in general, using the *past* tense for that sort of question is more idiomatic and sounds more natural:

> Where did this come from?

Using the *present perfect* in this case may sound a bit strange.

However, the *present perfect* form **is** sometimes used to imply that the asker is more interested not in knowing where it was before, but rather how it came to be here now:

> Q: Where did this plant come from?
>
> A: It came from Mary's house.  She was getting rid of it.

vs.

> Q: Where has this plant come from?
>
> A: Oh, I brought that over yesterday.

The present perfect is also used more often / interchangeably when talking about ideas rather than physical objects, to ask about the process by which something came about.  As an example, these two statements mean pretty much the same thing, and both sound perfectly natural:

> Where did this change of opinion come from?
>
> Where has this change of opinion come from?

But in general, if you're talking about a physical thing, and you want to know where it was before it was here, the *simple past* form is usually what you want.

---

As a side-note, when responding to a question in the *present perfect*, the answer is usually stated simply in the *past* tense, so even assuming the *present perfect* was correct for the question, this answer doesn't really sound right:

> It's come from Dallas, 5 miles from here.

Instead, that case should probably be phrased as:

> Q: Dude, where has this come from?
>
> A: It came from Dallas, 5 miles from here.